# nginx trailing slash rewrite results in a redirect loop

Tags: url, nginx

I'm using nginx for the first time and I can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to rewrite my nginx config so that all of my URLs no longer have the trailing slash that nginx defaults to.

I've been trying the following, but it still results in a redirect loop ("Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."):

```
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here and how I can remove trailing slashes?

Answer (score 4):

Actually... it's a firefox tendency to add a trailing slash to everything.

Your nginx config is removing it and firefox is adding it back to the request. Use 'curl -I' to check your config. Trying to enforce having or not having a trailing slash is going to cause you a lot of headaches.

If you absolutely need that, you need to remove the permanent and leave it an internal redirect.

From:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

To:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;
```

Comment: Thanks. The only helpful advice I've found on this issue is that browsers add the trailing slash back on and turn it into an infinite loop.